# ksh script: how redirect on the same file all stdout and stderr using exec, adding a different prefix?

Tags: redirect, exec, ksh

I'd like to..
on ksh
using exec on script begin
redirect both stdout and stderr on the same file
(and till here I got it)
but...
adding a different "prefix" to text line, one for stdout lines and one for stderr ones

let's say, 
if stdout produces "hallo stdout"
and stderr "hallo stderr"
on my dump file I'd like to have
FROM STDOUT : hallo stdout
FROM STDERR : hallo stderr

ps: hi everyone. That's my first....forget my bad english

Comment: Do you mean “exec” as in, replace the shell with it (then the exec can just be removed), or as in, all following lines should have the redirection (this is not possible because you need pipes for prefix addition, except when using FIFOs which is tricky but possible)?

Comment: Tring to answer,  I mean exec configuring output redirection fol all following istruction. The second case you mean, I beleive. So you say there's not an easy way... sob

Comment: yeah, it's easier to just put `{ … ;}` around all following commands and then append `| sed …` to that

Comment: forgive me ...i don't understand....I can use | only for stdout. Hot can I add a different suffix on stderr....let's say..."exec 2>&1 >all.out;{echo "orig stdout string" >&2} |awk {print "stderr_suffix" $0}"...? |will catch stdout..